# Bounding box not showing up in background subtracted video using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture("walking")
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
fgbg = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()
    while(1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        fgmask = cv.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(fgmask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv.drawContours(fgmask, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    if len(contours) > 0:
        for count in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(count)
            cv.rectangle(fgmask,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    cv.imshow("stan",frame)
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code, I am trying to get a box around the contours in the video which in this case is of multiple pedestrians walking. No box is showing up at all, am I making a simple mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation bug.  The drawing of the bounding boxes for the detected contours, as well as showing the results is not in the `while` loop.  Therefore, you are just reading in frames, finding the contours of these frames but you're not displaying them on the display window. 
 You need to do that for the frame to update as you're reading in the video.

Take the `while` loop and the first 5 lines that follow and move it to indentation level 0:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture("walking")
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
fgbg = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    fgmask = cv.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(fgmask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv.drawContours(fgmask, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 

    if len(contours) > 0:
        for count in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(count)
            cv.rectangle(fgmask,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    cv.imshow("stan",frame)
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```